# RequiredStringValidationBehavior stays always invalid

Tags: c#, validation, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

Here is the code in question:

```
            StackLayout myLayout = new StackLayout
            { 
                Children =
                {
                    new Entry(),

                    new Entry(),
                    
                    new Entry()
                }
            };

            myLayout.Children.OfType<Entry>().ElementAt(2).Behaviors.Add
            (
                new RequiredStringValidationBehavior
                {
                    RequiredString = myLayout.Children.OfType<Entry>().ElementAt(1).Text,
                    InvalidStyle = invalidEntryStyle,
                    Flags = ValidationFlags.ValidateOnValueChanging
                }
            );
```

I type the exact same text in the third entry as the text in the second one, yet the validator says that the input is invalid.

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: I tested the code you provided and it can recognize the element text but it can not judge the different between the two entry text. It may be the problem that it can not get the text when it changed I prefer you to use the INotifyPropertyChanged method to make it.

Comment: I have used `RequiredStringValidationBehavior` in XAML code and it works fine. The problem arises now that I have added it programmatically.

What do you mean by using `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Is this equivalent with using an event like `OnPropertyChanged` or `TextChanged`?

By the way. what do you mean with " It may be the problem that it can not get the text when it changed". Do you refer to the second entry or the third one?